# How to make equivalent of anonymous javascript function as paramter to IJSObjectReference in Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor

I'm working on a service in Blazor that's using a JavaScript map, and I need to add a plugin to that map. I have a script tag that references the library in my _Layout.cshtml file and then in the component that show the map I use

`@inject IJSRuntime JS`

And then

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        origo = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("Origo", "index.json");
    }       
}
```

But then I get stuck when I have to add the plugin to the map, in just plain HTML, to add the plugin would look like this

```
origo.on('load', function (viewer) {
    var draw = Draw({
        drawTools: {
            "Polygon": ["freehand", "box"],
            "LineString": ["freehand"]
        }
    });
    viewer.addComponent(draw);
});
```

I guess I have to make a new IJSObjectReference for the on function on origo, but how do I make an equivalent  of the anonymous function that is needed to add the plugin to the map? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something with a similar component that worked.  I created a JS file with an export function.  I cannot be certain about the exact code in this function, because I have no idea what plugin you are using and how it is initialized.

```
import "..."; //Import the JS library of the plugin

export function initPlugin() {

    //Initialize origo here...
    origo = ...

    origo.on('load', function (viewer) {
    var draw = Draw({
         drawTools: {
           "Polygon": ["freehand", "box"],
           "LineString": ["freehand"]
         }
   });
   viewer.addComponent(draw);

}
```

Then, from your razor code:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        jsStacksEditorImported = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./myscript.js");
        await jsStacksEditorImported.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("initPlugin");
    }
}
```